# c# Check task state after await

Tags: c#, task

Saw kind of this code in production:

```
var task = new HttpClient().GetAsync(u);
var response = await task;
if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Task is faulted: {task}");
}
```

Question: Does it make any sense to check the Task state after the `await` keyword? As far as I know, the compiler will build a state-machine "around" this code, which throws an exception in case of an error. Based on that it won't make any sense to check the Tasks state.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Don't create new `HttpClient` per request, refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples). `HttpResponseMessage` is `IDisposable`, it's important, implement `using`. You may not check `Task.IsCompletedSuccessfully` here but check `response.IsCompletedSuccessfully` , it will check if there HTTP 200 or something else. As alternative way you may throw an exception with method `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`.

Comment: Here's some [POST example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802872/12888024) but, GET is almost the same.

Comment: Without the await, is (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully) blocking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.

If there is an exception, then await will throw it. It wil lbasically not return the task, but the return value or throw the exception.

As such, there is no sense in evaluating the task further.

Otherwise the gain from await would be quite insignificant ;)

Comment: Note: `HttpResponseMessage` will not throw on HTTP response errors.

Comment: But that is not because of the task - it is because those are not exceptions. They are valid responses that contain an error and thus must be evaluated. Yes, I got an answer, but the answer may be a 404 or a 301.