# C# HttpClient Get very slow - calling from within a winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, httpclient

Based on [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802238/very-slow-httpclient-sendasync-call) - I changed my code because of a slow response when doing a simple Get - it takes about 54-50 seconds.  Posting to exactly the same URL using nodejs takes about 10 seconds.

```
    public class TrayWeighScan
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        public async Task<string> doOrder(string orderNumber, decimal weight ) 
        {
            var url = "http://r2hserver/logistics/weighscan?orderNumber="+orderNumber+"&weight="+weight.ToString("F2");
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws if 404, 500, etc.
                string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return responseText;
            }
        }
    }
```

and at the start of my winforms form I have

```
private TrayWeighScan trayWeighScan = new TrayWeighScan();
```

Then I call it with this code:

```
var jsonString = trayWeighScan.doOrder(barcode, Decimal.Parse(weight)).Result;
```

Comment: Don't use `.Result`. Use `await`. Especially in a WinForms (or anything else with a UI thread) application.

Comment: `var jsonString = await trayWeighScan.doOrder(barcode, Decimal.Parse(weight));` and make it `async Task` all the way up. The top-level event handler should be `async void`